# What does "cost hit to something" mean?

Tags: translation

Please help with understanding phrase

"cost hit to something"

The original sentence 
"Is there a cost hit to registering a new account for existing ones?"

Comment: Do you have a context?

Comment: Yes.
Is there a cost hit to registering a new account for existing ones?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: It is just email :) Do you need whole email ;)

Comment: @zaletniy: Maybe not the whole email, but never underestimate the value of providing **context**. For example, I can think of 5 different ways to use the word _cost_, and one dictionary lists [30 meanings](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hit) for the word _hit_. Sometimes one short sentence isn't enough to unequivocally decipher a meaning of a few words. Moreover, it's often worth knowing **where** a sentence was found; if it was found on a blog somewhere, it might mean the blogger is a poor writer; if it's found in the journal _Nature_, that's less likely to be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term *hit* can [mean](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/hit_2?q=take%20a%20hit) a loss

> to have to pay an unusual cost: *The company recently took a hit to the tune of $4 million in health insurance costs.*

The phrase *cost hit* does not appear to be a standard term, but it probably is being used to emphasize either a monetary loss or a loss of some other quantifiable value (points in a reputational tally, etc.).

The sense of the sentence appears to be

> If I register a new account, will I be penalized monetarily [or lose something from some other value system] in a way I would not if I continued to use existing accounts?

Comment: @StoneyB: In some environments, there might be more than one way to take "a hit." (On the Stack Exchange, for example, I might ask: "Will I take a rep hit if I change my account name?") So, if there was more than one way that a user could be adversely affected by creating a new account, then "cost hit" might not be redundant.

Comment: @J.R.- I think StoneyB meant that just saying, "Is there a cost" is sufficient.

Comment: @Jim I don't disagee in most cases, but there might be alternative *hits*, such as causing a delay or a lesser quality of outcome as well as charging fees or losing points. *Cost hit* suggest that there will be an asset dimunition, not just a *hit* of inconvenience or other negative effect.

Answer (score 0):

*Hit can be used to express a negative impact to something, for example a *performance hit* means performance has decreased.

But in this case it sounds like redundant business jargon to me. A *cost hit* can be simply replaced by *cost*:

> "Is there a cost to registering a new account for existing ones?"

Or perhaps:

> "What does it cost for existing users to register a new account?"